# How can I change video codecs for Chrome/YouTube?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, codec

Today I opened [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRgjgs3NnnE) which is available in 720p and 1080p at 50 fps.

For some reason my laptop can't handle it. I have Core 2 Duo T9300 2.5GHz. Single core performance of this CPU is just 30% worse than most modern processors, but... it hass no hardware x.264 decoding (YouTube uses x.264, right?). However - I have Nvidia Quadro in this laptop, it has some hardware decoding acceleration and normally - I can watch HD 50fps video. But not in Chrome.

I'm using K-Lite Codec Pack Full. I have tried to change decoder to LAV in "Codec tweak tool", because I have no performance problems with it.

[image]

**Is there any way to force Chrome to use diffrent codec?**

---

Edit/update: I turned OFF hardware acceleration in Chrome and there is no performance problem anymore, but I still want to know how to force Chrome to use LAV (or ffdshow).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your GPU is not supported in Google Chrome. You should type `chrome://flags` and then search `#ignore-gpu-blacklist` and enable that. It should now enable hardware acceleration.